# How to convert single line xml to indent without withspace using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am converting single line XML to Indent without white-space my output generate indent but whitespace is come before node.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><article xmlns="http://jats.nlm.nih.gov" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:tf="http://cats.informa.com/tfjats" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" article-type="research-article" tf:schema-version="1.0" xml:lang="en"><tf:article-status stage="ahead-of-issue"><tf:tagger name="cenveo"/></tf:article-status><front><journal-meta><journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">ABCD</journal-id><journal-id journal-id-type="title-id">vjee20</journal-id><journal-title-group><journal-title>aaaaaaaaaaaa</journal-title></journal-title-group><issn pub-type="ppub">0095</issn><issn pub-type="epub">1940-1892</issn><publisher><publisher-name>RTZ</publisher-name></publisher></journal-meta><article-meta><article-id pub-id-type="doi">1687404</article-id><article-id pub-id-type="publisher-id">1687404</article-id><article-id pub-id-type="submission-id">02-19-010.R1</article-id><article-categories><series-title content-type="article-type">Article</series-title></article-categories><title-group><article-title>I need to </article-title><alt-title alt-title-type="running-authors">ANNE B. REINERTSEN</alt-title><alt-title alt-title-type="running-title">The Journal of Environmental Education</alt-title></title-group><contrib-group><contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Reinertsen</surname><given-names>Anne B.</given-names></name><xref ref-type="corresp" rid="AN0001"/><xref ref-type="aff" rid="AF0001"/></contrib><aff id="AF0001"><institution><tf:institution-name>&#x000D8;stfold University College</tf:institution-name></institution><x>, </x><tf:city>Halden</tf:city><x>, </x><country>Norway</country></aff></contrib-group><author-notes><fn id="AUFN1"><p>The JEE 50th Anniversary Special Issue</p></fn><fn id="AUFN2"><p>A 50-&#x02009;year Retrospective on Environmental Education Inquiry: Recognizing the Past and Challenging the Future</p></fn><corresp id="AN0001"><bold>CONTACT</bold> Anne B. Reinertsen <email>Anne.B.Reinertsen@hiof.no</email><institution><tf:institution-name>&#x000D8;stfold University College</tf:institution-name></institution><x>, </x><addr-line>BRA veien 4</addr-line><x>, </x><tf:city>Halden</tf:city><tf:postal-code>1781</tf:postal-code><x>, </x><country>Norway</country><?A3B2 show [zaq no="AQ1"]?><?A3B2 show [zaq no="AQ2"]?></corresp></author-notes><pub-date pub-type="epub" date-type="control" iso-8601-date="2019-11-11"/><volume>0</volume><issue>0</issue><fpage>1</fpage><lpage>12</lpage><permissions><copyright-statement>&#x000A9; 2019 Taylor &#x00026; Francis Group, LLC</copyright-statement><copyright-year>2019</copyright-year><copyright-holder>Taylor &#x00026; Francis</copyright-holder></permissions><self-uri content-type="pdf" xlink:href="VJEE_A_1687404_O.pdf"/><abstract><p>This article all.</p></abstract><kwd-group kwd-group-type="author"><title>KEYWORDS</title><kwd>assessment as learning</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>critical lemon studies</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>data philosophy</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>fuzzytechie innovations</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>intra-factual molecularity connections</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>nature as event</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>natureculture</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>ontology of sustainability</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>pedagogy as scientific subject matter</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>reassessment apparatus;research as activism</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>transcorporeal collectivities</kwd><x>; </x><kwd>writing</kwd></kwd-group><counts><fig-count count="0"/><table-count count="0"/><page-count count="12"/><word-count count="5789"/></counts></article-meta></front><body><sec id="s0001"><title>The thing is that </title><disp-quote content-type="extract"><p>The concept of the other, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CIT0006">1994</xref>, p. 17&#x00029;</p></disp-quote><p>Teaching becomes <italic>eventicized</italic> and teachers and researchers become <italic>data philosophers</italic> through writing. Writing is seen as a technical object never giving up on &#x0201C;optative&#x0201D;, i.e., that by which every problem can be thought and reflected upon according to its multiple dimensions &#x00028;Simondon, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CIT0016">1958</xref>/2012/2017&#x00029;. Writing is considered both method and tool, or rather, this is a move from method to writing and the use of one&#x02019;s maximal attention. Data, ultimately nature seen as event &#x00028;Debaise, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CIT0003">2017</xref></p><p>The concept</p><p>It implies  other&#x02019;s motifs.<?A3B2 show [zaq no="AQ5"]?><?A3B2 show [zaq no="AQ6"]?> A theory of, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CIT0014">2018a</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CIT0012">b</xref>&#x00029;.</p><p>Private images</p></sec></body><back><ref-list><title>References</title><ref id="CIT0001"><mixed-citation publication-type="journal"><person-group person-group-type="author"><string-name><surname>Alaimo</surname>, <given-names>S.</given-names></string-name></person-group> &#x00028;<year>2012</year>&#x00029;. <article-title>Sustainable this, sustainable that: New materialisms, posthumanism, and unknown futures</article-title>. <source><italic>PMLA</italic></source>, <volume><italic>127</italic></volume>&#x00028;<issue>3</issue>&#x00029;, <fpage>558</fpage>&#x02013;<lpage>564</lpage>. doi:<pub-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1632/pmla.2012.127.3.558</pub-id></mixed-citation></ref></ref-list></back></article>
```

**XSLT CODE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:tf="http://cats.informa.com/tfjats" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xpath-default-namespace="http://jats.nlm.nih.gov"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://jats.nlm.nih.gov" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:tf="http://cats.informa.com/tfjats" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" article-type="research-article" tf:schema-version="1.0" xml:lang="en" dtd-version="TFJATS-1.0">
<tf:article-status stage="ahead-of-issue">
<tf:tagger name="abcd"/>
</tf:article-status>
<front>
<journal-meta>
<journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">ABCD</journal-id>
<journal-id journal-id-type="title-id">vjee20</journal-id>
<journal-title-group>
</front>
...........
<back>
<ref-list>
<title>References</title>
<ref id="CIT0001">
<mixed-citation publication-type="journal">
<person-group person-group-type="author">
<string-name name-style="western">
<surname>Alaimo</surname>, <given-names>S.</given-names>
</string-name>
</person-group> (<year>2012</year>). <article-title>Sustainable this, sustainable that: New materialisms, posthumanism, and unknown futures</article-title>. <source>
<italic>PMLA</italic>
</source>, <volume>
<italic>127</italic>
</volume>(<issue>3</issue>), <fpage>558</fpage>–<lpage>564</lpage>. doi:<pub-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1632/pmla.2012.127.3.558</pub-id>
</mixed-citation>
</ref>
</ref-list>
</back>
</article>
```

I want to expected This output.

Comment: Indent means indent. With some processors you can control the *amount* of indentation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, if i have use this xslt then output generate indent but is it possible before node remove white-space?

Comment: It *may* be possible to set the amount of indentation to 0 (which is what your output shows). Depends on your processor. With some, 0 is the default - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPg

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, Thanks for the reply but Sir I am using Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12 how is it possible this Saxon indentation to 0?

Comment: Try adding `saxon:indent-spaces="0"` to `xsl:output` - see: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, when I am using This namespace xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" or <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" saxon:indent-spaces="0"/> but 1st line in article attribute in new line showing. How can I 1st line attribute in single line?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I suggest you show the problem in your question - and add a `saxon` tag to it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, Many many Thanks! for Help me.